# c# mysql - add the value of stock and new entries when the description is the same

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, duplicates, addition

Sorry guys to my english..

when i insert a record the same description with the existing record in datagridview but different quantity.. it creates a new row for the last record i inserted...

what i want is to ADD the quantity i inserted to the old record with the same description..

[1. HERE'S THE IMAGE FOR YOU TO UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsdn7.jpg)

[2. THIS IS WHAT HAPPEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkOiY.jpg)

The result should be QUANTITY = 25..  and also the totalcbm.. totalcbm = quantity * cbm

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory(Quantity,Unit,ItemCode,ItemName,Cbm,TotalCbm)VALUES(@Quantity,@Unit,@ItemCode,@ItemName,@Cbm,@TotalCbm)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", tbQuantity.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", tbUnit.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", tbItemCode.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", tbItemName.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cbm", tbCbm.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCbm", tbTotalCbm.Text.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
                frmUserAE form1 = new frmUserAE();
                AccountForm.LoadGrid();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an INSERT statement, which will create a new row.

You should do an UPDATE statement, depending on what you think is your primary key (the description?).

Comment: oww.. sorry i forgot.. when i insert an item without same item desc. it will add a new row/record.. but when you insert an item with same item desc it will update only

Comment: it is like IF ELSE statement.. but i dont know how to use it to mysql dbase to know if there's the same item desc

Comment: What you could do is always insert a new row, then in your sql statement that populates the grid, you GROUP BY Description and SUM the quantity.